# Grep color on multiple file search

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

I've been searching all over for this and I've found a plethora of responses but unfortunately not exactly what I'm looking for. That's probably due to the fact that I'm not quite sure how to explain it. Here goes.

I'm using Ubuntu and running grep on multiple files:

grep text file1 file2 file3

When I get my return back it's hard to read part of it because of the dark blue against black. I've already edited .bashrc to do my color coding...however, it's not the search result but the file name that I can't see. Let me show you:

[image]

As you can see....to the left of the red 'text' it says file1 and file2. Can anyone tell me how to change the color of that particular section of the output.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: change color scheme for your terminal.

Option 2: `grep text file1 file2 file3 > /tmp/res.txt` and now you can open `/tmp/res.txt` file in editor with nice colors.

Comment: That did it Vladimir. I had an alias pre-defined in my .bashrc. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* that your `grep` is an alias, do `which grep` to check it.

Anyway, you can do `grep --color=never text file....` to get result not in color.